# SQL & database setup for downline-builder application

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm currently building a site for a client who wants a **downloadbuilder** or something.  Basically it's a site with a signupform and every member has a **referral-url** that contains their referral-id so when someone joins they are placed as **downline member** in a sort of **pyramidal structure**.

The **site itself contains a page with links to other MLM type sites**, so the person who just joins will be in the downline of someone and will be shown the **referral links to other MLM sites** with the **referral-id of his upline** for the **respective MLM sites**.

**If** these **new members** decide to **follow their upline** and **become also member of the other MLM sites** he/she can **replace the urls** to these sites **with their referral-urls** for the MLM programs. This is all pretty straightforward and relatively easy to build.

The **tricky part** is **once a new member doesn't follow his/her upline for a certain MLM program**, if that's the case **the downline** of this new member **will see the referral-ids of the upline of the new member** **or the first in the hierarchy** who did enter his referral-url.

For example **Mr Brown** in the image below, **joins only program 1 & 2** his **downline** sees all three programs but one of them **join only program 2 & 3** this means that **for program 3 his direct upline will be the upline of Mr Brown**.(see purple line).

[image]

It's this part that I'm unsure about how can I do this, without complex recursive lookup and what if someone quits or leaves the site?

Is there a way to do such a lookup with **SQL or any other technique**.  I thought of **storing a 'path' in a column** of a table **with the lineage of the uplines** for each new member so it's relatively easy to find the parent, grandparent and so on.  But still you need to **recursively** go through this path to find the first one with a referral-url.  Also if you **delete** someone from the tree **all paths need to be updated** to reflect the new situation.

There's no limit to how deep or wide the tree can become.

I hope this is not too confusing.  And btw it's NOT an April fools joke, I really wish it was...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know when presenting Mr. Z (who is referred by Mr. Brown), the Mr. Z is downline of Mr. Brown. I'll also assume you store this referral information.

When you show Mr. Z all programs, when Mr. Z signs up for a program, you could simple walk the referral information and determine if that person has signed up for the same program. If Yes, then you can store the downline information link to Mr. Browns Program 1 recoord. If Mr. Brown is not signed up, then using the referral data, you could walk to who referred Mr. Brown and check the same.

Hopefully that makes sense, I am not familiar enough with MySql, but using code it should be pretty easy to do this recursively. Some sample psuedo code:

```
int GetUplineProgramId(User, ProgramID)
     Select All ProgramID's that the person who referred me signed up for
     If my referred is signed up for program, then return that record ID
     else return GetUplineProgramId(my referrals UserID, ProgramID)
end
```

Comment: I figured out I could do something like this but it's the recursive part that bothers me if you have like 40 000 people in your tree (there are downline builders with this amount of people really!) this recursive lookup can become slow.  

Also what if someone deletes himself from the tree?  There are probably SQL solutions to this without having to do the recursive programming in the serverside language

Comment: if a user deletes himself, I think your answer is to have a flag that says this user is deleted, and keep all the records. You're right that recurrsion could be costly. I agree there is surely a SQL solution, however, it will likely have to be recursive. It would still be significantly faster than doing it in code and hitting the DB a ton of times passing data around.

Comment: Yes I think a soft delete of a user is an option and than just ignoring the user in the tree when returning results, this way the tree doesn't have to be updated on each delete.  I still wonder if how the SQL would look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of my depth for recursive queries on MySql. I found this link from a mysql mailing list that looks relevant: [http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html)